# CS0103 Error on some obviously in-scope variables - .NET Forms

Tags: c#

Below is a small code snippet from a large C# Forms application.  This and all the other code in the application has worked properly through numerous iterations of VS and still does with the latest version of VS2022 Community.

In the past I have been able to view the values of any variables in the program by breakpointing with them in scope then hovering over them or putting them in the watch list.  However, I can no longer do this for a large percentage of them.  Instead, the hover shows nothing and a CS0103 error shows in the watch list.

For example, when I breakpoint on the "if (indexOfItem > -1)" line of the code below the only variables that can be hovered or do not produce a CS0103 watch error are regex_MatchNameForDirectory, SectionInfos, comboBox_Sections, and comboBox_Sections.SelectedIndex, yet the code itself works perfectly.  I don't know when this issue started but I assume it was due to some configuration change or VS update.

I have searched the Web and this site for this issue but still have not been able to resolve it.

```
     Match m = regex_MatchNameForDirectory.Match(Settings.Default.SelectedSection);
     if (m.Success)
     {
        string sectionKey = m.Groups["sectionID"].Value;
        if (SectionInfos.ContainsKey(sectionKey))
        {
           string nameInComboBox = SectionInfos[sectionKey].NameForDirectory;
           int indexOfItem = comboBox_Sections.FindStringExact(nameInComboBox);
           if (indexOfItem > -1)
              comboBox_Sections.SelectedIndex = indexOfItem;
        }
     }
```

Comment: You're getting a compile error? The code you've posted is fine. I think you need to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Any chance you're trying to debug something built in release mode, where things might have been optimized away? Alternatively, since resolving local variable names specifically requires correct debugging symbols (as opposed to members, whose names are always available by virtue of metadata), something may have gone wonky there -- double check the settings that govern the generating of these. Try a full clean and rebuild of the application first.

Comment: Right click the solution and select `Clean Solution` then `Rebuild`. Then tell us what the error is and its location.

Comment: I am not getting any kind of compiler error or warning and the runtime code works perfectly.  The issue is during debugging when trying to view the values of some variables when stopped at a breakpoint.  The project is being built in the Debug mode and it does reach the body of the innermost "if" statement.  I suppose it's possible that it's optimizing away all the local variables but I don't see why that should be happening.  Is there a way to prevent such optimizations when in the Debug mode?

Comment: If you have rebuilt, there is something wrong with the `.pdb` files, they don't match what has been built; hence the failure to land on the line you expect. Long story short, is you need to get a fresh debug build. Trying cleaning release and debug. If that fails delete the obj and bin directories by hand and rebuild.